# Chrome extension equivalent for firefox add-on sidebar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am trying to create chrome extension that will create floating overlay (static one that dose not refresh), Similar to firefox add-on "ui sidebar"

Is there any way to maintain iframe like overlay that wont be effected by the page, and wont be reloaded when the tab reloads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is **NO**.

What you are describing is basically called browser chrome, i. e. UI. The only chrome Google Chrome extensions support since forever are page actions and browser actions.

Opera also supports [sidebar actions](https://dev.opera.com/extensions/sidebar-action-api/). Rumor is, Firefox WebExtensions [will support](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1208596) that too.

Chrome has no support however. It's on the [wishlist](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/apiwishlist) but has no actual [proposal/intent to ship](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19jw1oWKGV5xi2vbNlQLp0WH5M8NxCv9x0kokV3z1dYY/edit#gid=0). Apparently, there has been a [recent decision not to pursue this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477424#c82).

Comment: It won't come. Recent decision: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477424#c82

Comment: Thanks for the great answer